# want to insert $_post data in to temporary table

Tags: php

here is my code is there any syntax error, kindly guide me

```
$degree = $_POST['edu'];

$board  = $_POST['bu'];

$result = $_POST['rdd'];

$marks  = $_POST['tm'];

$maketemp = "CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE temp_table_1 ( `degree` varchar(100),`board` varchar(100),`resultd` varchar(100), `marks` varchar(100),)";

mysql_query($maketemp);

$insertemp = "INSERT INTO temp_table_1 (degree, board, resultd, marks ) VALUES ('$degree', '$board', '$resultd', '$marks',) ";

mysql_query($insertemp);

$show =  mysql_query("SELECT * FROM temp_table_1");


if($show)
{
    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($show)){

        echo $row['degree'];
    }
```

Comment: Does it work or doesn't it?

Comment: what error are you facing? there are some syntax errors in this code you should fix first, like the missing closing braces for the `if` condition.

Comment: Remove TEMPORARY  and ',' from the end                         $maketemp = "CREATE TABLE temp_table_1 ( `degree` varchar(100),`board` varchar(100),`resultd` varchar(100), `marks` varchar(100))";

Answer (score 1):

Syntax error in your both query, just replace your both query with this...

```
$maketemp = "CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE temp_table_1 ( `degree` varchar(100),`board` 
varchar(100),`resultd` varchar(100), `marks` varchar(100))";  // removed last comma

  mysql_query($maketemp);

$insertemp = "INSERT INTO temp_table_1 (degree, board, resultd, marks ) VALUES ('$degree', 
'$board', '$resultd', '$marks') ";  // removed last comma
```

Comment: thanks Sumit,, i removed ',' the comas ,,now the code is working good,,an i get the result

Comment: now i will get values from this temporary table on the next page and insert in to the database table

Answer (score 0):

There are some errors in query.
Remove TEMPORARY and ',' from the end of query in create table.

Change it to this

```
CREATE TABLE temp_table_1 ( `degree` varchar(100),`board` varchar(100),`resultd` varchar(100), `marks` varchar(100))

INSERT INTO temp_table_1 (degree, board, resultd, marks ) VALUES ('".$degree."','".$board."','".$resultd."', "'.$marks."'")
```

Answer (score 0):

I find 4 Errors:

```
Extra comma after`marks` varchar(100)
Extra comma after '$marks'
Missing 'd' on $result = $_POST['rdd'];
Missing end brace of the if statement
```

Below is a working version. I recommend using the

```
    die( die(mysql_error() . "<br>Query: " . ...)
```

after every mysql_query(). It gives lots of help.

```
$degree = $_POST['edu'];
$board = $_POST['bu'];
$resultd = $_POST['rdd'];
$marks = $_POST['tm'];

$maketemp = "CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE temp_table_1 ( 
    `degree` varchar(100),
    `board` varchar(100),
    `resultd` varchar(100), 
    `marks` varchar(100)
)";

mysql_query($maketemp) or die(mysql_error() . "<br>Query: " . $maketemp);

$insertemp = "INSERT INTO temp_table_1 (
    degree, board, resultd, marks 
    ) VALUES (
    '$degree', '$board', '$resultd', '$marks'
) ";

mysql_query($insertemp) or die(mysql_error() . "<br>Query: " . $inserttemp);

$select_temp = "SELECT * FROM temp_table_1";
$show = mysql_query($select_temp)  or die(mysql_error() . "<br>Query: " . $select_temp);

if($show) { 

    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($show)){
      echo "<br>".$row['degree'];
      echo "<br>".$row['board'];
      echo "<br>".$row['resultd'];
      echo "<br>".$row['marks'];
    }

}
?>
```